Re-encrypting a mailitem using property accessor
I need to decrypt a mailitem, save it as .msg, then re-encrypt it, so the original mail seems unaltered.
OUTLOOK VSTO ADDIN C#
// Decrypt the mail item
const string PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003";
Outlook.PropertyAccessor propertyAccessor = mailItem.PropertyAccessor;
propertyAccessor.SetProperty(PR_SECURITY_FLAGS, 0x00000000); // Decrypt the mail item
mailItem.Save();

// Save the decrypted mail item
mailItem.SaveAs(filePathWithName);

// Re-encrypt the mail item
propertyAccessor.SetProperty(PR_SECURITY_FLAGS, 0x00000001); // Encrypt the mail item
mailItem.Save();

This code decrypts an smime encrypted email and saves it as .msg.
The last bit, re-encrypting is not working.

Outlook would not be able to encrypt a message back even in theory - the whole point of encryption/signing is to ensure the message is not tampered with. If you could do that, it means you can modify a message without invalidating its signature. More than that, you'd need to have the private encryption key to encrypt it - decryption only requires the public key.
You can try to make a copy of the message to decrypt it, save as MSG file, then delete the copy.
You can also try to use Redemption (I am its author) to access the decrypted message and save it: create an instance of the RDOSession object, call RDOSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(mailItem) / RDOEncryptedMessage.GetDecryptedMessage / RDOMail.SaveAs.
